# I'm starting to believe that my python installation is broken

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

How can this happen?

```
/home/gui/Documents/GIT/Neuraxle/neuraxle/hyperparams/distributions.py in rvs(self)
    282         :return: an integer.
    283         """
--> 284         return round(float(self.hd.rvs()))
    285 
    286     def narrow_space_from_best_guess(self, best_guess, kept_space_ratio: float = 0.5) -> 'Quantized':

TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method
```

I got tons of weird errors like this one today. And no, I didn't do something stupid like `float = np.array`. The `float` method is the original one. Using python 3.6.7.

Note: the library I'm coding is installed in editable mode as such: `sudo -H pip3 install --editable .` The editable installation seems to fail, and resinstalling with `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --editable .` only temporarily fixes the problem.

Comment: [mcve]. You know the drill.

Comment: This sounds like you edited your code without restarting Python. Restart Python.

Comment: Also delete your `.pyc` files.

Comment: @MFisherKDX: this bug is NOT reproducible: the thing is unstable and the bug changed constantly. In spite of that, for your reference, the code is already public, here is the commit: https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle/commit/b9cc13bc88fb544427e3c17a2f7f5adf60ad8548
So finally I fixed this, it had to do with bad `.pyc` files. See my answer.

Comment: In consequence, this is why I've been so general in the title of the question. The thing was changing so much that I had no other anchor than to think it was about the python installation or something like that.

Comment: And thank you @user2357112. Python was restarted, but it was really the pyc files. To me, you'd owe to have the best answer and an upvote of me if you answer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the library was installed in editable mode and that this caused some trouble with the .pyc files upon editing. Here is a fix if anyone encounter this problem. To run this, you should be in the folder where the "setup.py" is, and inside a git repository:

```
# Remove all .pyc files in the current git project
find $(git rev-parse --show-cdup) -name "*.pyc" -delete

# Completely reinstall the project
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --editable .
```

EDIT: if you can avoid installing the project in editable mode altogether, that's even better. So skip redoing `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --editable .` ideally.